# How to assign controller to iFrame in Ionic App?

Tags: angularjs, iframe, iconic

How would i achieve controller assigning to iframe places in an ionic app?

should i use ng-controller attribute on a div in iframe or will contoller of parent pafe, i.e. page that contains iframe be used from within iframe?

Edit:
To set a context,
Case1: I want to bind a property within iFrame whose src is a local html page, which is fetching some data and I want to set dynamic URL or set some property (dynamically) which is bound to controller.

Case2: Suppose iFrame is rendering some local html page which has  tag, now I want to call controller function on click of that anchor, how do I call that?

Comment: you should use inappBrowser in your application instead of iframe.. it will provide more facilities.

Comment: But even with inAppBrowser, I'll open my local HTML based page using 'code' window.open('/localPage.html','_blank');
Now how do I bind a property within localPage.html to a controller based variable?

Comment: Please refer cases I added to question